# calling a coldfusion function from another function via ajax rendering an error

Tags: ajax, function, coldfusion

Here's the deal:  I am sending an ajax request to a coldfusion function, which then calls another function inside the same component.  Here are the two functions:

```
<!--- test--->
<cffunction name="deleteMission" access="public" output="No" returntype="struct">
 <cfscript>
  var returnData = structNew();
  structAppend(returnData, getTest());
  returnData.test2 = "test2";
 </cfscript>
 <cfreturn returnData>
</cffunction>

<!--- test2 --->
<cffunction name="getTest" access="public" output="No" returntype="struct">
 <cfscript>
  var returnData = structNew();
 returnData.testing = "TEST";
</cfscript>
 <cfreturn returnData>
</cffunction>
```

Very simple, just returning 2 struct keys in this example.  If I call the method test() regularly (ie, on page load via coldfusion), I get the expected results.  However, if I call the method test() via AJAX, I receive the error "Variable getTest is undefined."  If I remove the call to getTest(), I receive the single struct key back as expected.  Anyone have any idea what is going on?  I have a feeling it's something simple I've overlooked, but I need some more eyeballs on it at this point... I'm really scratching my head on this one.  Thanks!

Comment: "If I remove the call to getTest(), I receive the single struct key back as expected."  I don't understand, what's your ajax call URL? Post your ajax script!

Comment: where is method test()?  There's only deleteMission() & getTest() in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're accessing the component via AJAX, then the `access` attribute of your `cffunction` should be set to `remote`. E.g.

```
<cffunction name="deleteMission" access="remote" output="No" returntype="struct">
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your getTest to access="private". 
Also, Sometimes the StructAppend method does not take in parameters as "function call". So get the value into a variable first and then send that variable to deleteMission.

something like this...

```
var inpData = getTest();
structAppend(returnData, inpData);
```